# asp.net mvc int property bind exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a int property  in my class and want to validate if the user has entered a string.
How can I do that using data annotations? 
When I pass a non-integer value I get a excpetion like this:

```
The value 'asdasd' is not valid for property.
```

For example using this validation attribute:

```
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Invalid Number")]
public int? Number { get; set; }
```

and entering 'aaa' in a field tha uses the model I've got an excepetion with this message:

```
The value 'aaa' is not valid for Number.
```

Instead of the "Invalid Number" message.

Any Ideas?

---

I've put

```
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Invalid Number")]
public int? Number { get; set; }
```

but I've got this message from an excpetion

```
The value 'aaa' is not valid for Number.
```

Comment: I'm using a string and trying to converto to int, but I think that is not the correct way to validate this issue.

Comment: What is wrong with whats happening now?  The model binder is validating the int just fine.

Comment: I think an exception could be what you want. Check out the `HandleError` attribute.

Comment: Could you clarify what result you would like to achieve?

Comment: I'm want to show a custom error message to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two stages of validation at play here.

Before the validation set up in your attributes is called, the framework first attempts to parse the information.

So here are a couple of examples based on this code:

```
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Invalid Number")]
public int? Number { get; set; }
```

**I type nothing into the box...**

"Invalid Number" (Framework will create a null integer, your validation rule fails)

**I type "A" into the box...**

"The value 'A' is not valid for Number." (Framework cannot convert "A" into a nullable int, so the framework validation rule fails and your validation rule it not checked.

** Solutions **

1 - Live with the default message until you are using MVC 3 / .NET 4, which makes it easier to override these messages

2 - Exclude the value from the binder, so it won't cause an error (but you will have to bind it and check it yourself)

```
[Bind(Exclude="MyNumber")]
```

3 - Make it a string on the model, then test it with a TryParse and add your own custom model error (This is a reasonable practice and reminds us all why View Models are used rather than Domain Objects!)

```
if (!Int32.TryParse("MyNumber", out myInteger)) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("MyNumber", "That isn't a number!");
}
```

There are actually lots of solutions, but I would say go with option 3 for now.

Comment: Does MVC3 make Sohnee's solution easier?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a Range-attribute on your model-field like so:

```
[Range(0, 9999)]
public int Something {get; set;}
```

Now whenever the user inputs a string it will not validate, and also the int must be between 0-9999

this should also work with

```
[Range(0, 9999)]
public string Something {get; set;}
```

and

```
[Range(0, 9999)]
public object Something {get; set;}
```