# Data Annotation - wrong error message for numbers

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have a double variable :

```
 public double Width { set; get; }
```

I want to validate the number and display an error message so I added:

```
[Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Width must be a valid number")]
```

It works great if I enter a negative number, but if I leave it empty or enter letters - the inner error message is

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

I'm not usign  @html.validationmessagefor , because I need to handle the ModelState's ErrorMessage or error.exception.InnerException.message manually.

How can I fix that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451255/asp-net-mvc-int-property-bind-exception

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this error message comes from a `double.Parse`

the Data Annotation attributes are not used by the double class, they are just used by some frameworks.

anyway it looks like your input string was no valid double, so a range validation has nothing to do with a valid double string.

Comment: I create a viewmodel by JS and that send it so maybe this is why it uses double.parse? Anyway, how can I change the text for this message also?

Comment: perhaps in an onvalidation event, you can check it by the double.TryParse function, and then throw if needed a new own made exception

Comment: hmm.. I don't have the original value. If I enter "abc" indstead of a number - I get "0.0" in "Width", and "ModelState.IsValid" is false;